# AppSpec file was expected but not found at path "/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/843bf9-ac/d-0PULFH/deployment-archive/appspec.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, on-premises-instances, aws-code-deploy-appspec

i am trying to codedeploy into my local ubuntu system, via aws on-premises codedeployment.

the content from my remote repository successfully got downloaded to my local ubuntu as bundle.tar and unzipped all the contents in deployment-archives folder
but it is not installing the unzipped content to the destination specified in appspec.yml

the error in logs is :
The revision was unpacked to directory "/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/843dabf9-acaf-43e3-937d-6beb5c941cc6/d-0PU6KPLFH/deployment-archive", and the AppSpec file was expected but not found at path "/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/843dabf9-acaf-43e3-937d-6beb5c941cc6/d-0PU6KPLFH/deployment-archive/appspec.yml
Consult the AWS CodeDeploy Appspec documentation for more information at [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file.html\](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file.html%5C)

but when i open the dir the appspec.yml file does exists in the folder (deployment-archive/)
looks like the codedeploy agent is unable to find the file, or is trying to find it before bundle.tar is unzipped??

although it works perfectly fine when i use an aws ec2 or lightsail as an onpremise server